# In ASP.NET, how do I detect a password in a Word 2003 or 2007 file?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ms-word, ms-office, docx

My users like to upload password-protected Word documents into our custom document management system.  I'd like to add a validation to check for the password and refuse the upload if it has a password.

Automating Word - with COM interop - is out of the question because this is a server side application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not available directly from .NET or [DSOFile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;q224351), but you could create a wrapper in .NET to read the [PIDSI_DOC_SECURITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942506%28PROT.13%29.aspx) property of any Office file to find out if it is password-protected or not without opening the document. There are a number of [C++ samples](http://kbalertz.com/Feedback.aspx?kbNumber=186898) out there that could be ported with a definition of `iPropertyStorage`.

A wrapped example is on [TechTarget](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid26_cid506977,00.html), but the wrapper seems to be unavailable.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is going to depend on the version of Microsoft Word.  Older versions of Word (before 2007) will require some COM interop, because they are not saved in an open format.  Nothing you can do to get around that, and I feel your frustrations with installing anything Office on a web server.  Additionally, I believe the only way to detect password protection on these is to attempt to open/unprotect the file and catch a certain exception (you may have to further evaluate an error code within the exception as well).  Not pretty!

However, for newer versions of word (2007+) saved in the open DOCX format ([Standard ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/flat/publications/Standards/Ecma-376.htm)), you can examine the XML and check for the existence of the `DocumentProtection` element with the `w:enforcement` attribute set to "on"...

```
<w:DocumentProtection
   w:edit="read-only"
   w:enforcement="on"
   w:unprotectPassword="1FC6CBEB"/>
```

Note: The password seen here is encrypted (obviously); I saved this particular document with a password of "test".

Comment: I wish I could split the bounty! (I checked the FAQ to see if I could).  This is indeed half of the answer. Otaku had the other half, thanks!

Comment: @Matthew I am not here for points; glad to hear you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you'd like to open/examine Word documents without using any Office interop at all?  Good luck!

Possibly your only place to start would be to manually parse the docx yourself (the spec is published [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)).  Really though, I'd suggest you bite the bullet and use the Office interop libraries, 'cause that's a much lighter weight requirement than parsing the document yourself.  There's nothing that intrinsically *prevents* you doing that on a server application.

Comment: re: prevention... Well, there are the licensing restrictions on Office Apps and its not always easy to convince a server administrator to install MS Office on a server, especially when MS-Office interop running in ASP.NET often leads to 100s of exel.exe and word.exe processes on the server.

Comment: That's just another problem to solve, not a complete blocker.  If you have sufficient business need then your admins will have to cede to that (and you have to deal with the ramifications); if not, then you need to find a different solution.

Comment: um. no! Office running on the server is an unsupported configuration and something best left to dodgy hacker admins. If your trying to solve that problem, your solving the wrong problem.